# How to write annotation for documentation in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I would like to add documentation in source code not attached to any specific Kotlin class or method, it's like conceptual, high-level documentation.

I would like to keep it in the Kotlin source file, close to things it describes.

Ideally I would like to be able to write it as:

```
...
doc(
  title = "Some title",
  text  = "Some text"
)
...
```

But it's not possible as Kotlin won't allow top level calls, I also tried to use annotations, but it's also not allowed without attaching something to it.

```
@Doc(
  title = "Some title",
  text  = "Some text"
)
```

So, the code below works but it's not looks nice. Is there something better?

```
@Doc private val doc1 = doc(
  title = "Some title",
  text  = "Some text"
)
```

Or maybe

```
@Doc(
  title = "Some title",
  text  = "Some text"
) val tmp = 0
```

Comment: I think it is not necessary to use this annotation. If you read the kotlin documentation you can find the possibility to write also a documentation for [packages and modules](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html#module-and-package-documentation). Or another possibility would be to add a simple file e.g. markdown file to write necessary notes or the most times you have also a wiki or something else, maye it is better to write some conceptual things in the wiki e.g. Confluence, GithHub Wiki, ...

Comment: Why an annotation? Do you need to parse it at runtime?